# How to repeat a index once it is is finished going through back to the beginning

Tags: python, pygame

I realized that when I finished and ran my code that it didn't repeat the index, so I brainstormed and couldn't think of anything. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
import pygame

current_image = 0

img_names = ["frame_00_delay-0.01s.gif", "frame_01_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_02_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_03_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_04_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_05_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_06_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_07_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_08_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_09_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_10_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_11_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_12_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_13_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_14_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_15_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_16_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_17_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_18_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_19_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_20_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_21_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_22_delay-0.1s.gif",
             "frame_23_delay-0.1s.gif", "frame_24_delay-0.1s.gif"]
imgs = [pygame.image.load(img) for img in img_names]
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            current_image += 1
    display_surface.blit(imgs[current_image], (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    if current_image >= 3:
        intro = False
        run = True
```

All I need it to do is when you get to frame 24 (the last one) for it to go back to frame 0 in the index.

Comment: Really???   `current_image = (current_image + 1) % len(img_names)`

Comment: if current_image == 24:<br>

Answer (score 3):

Use `cycle` from `itertools`:

Example:

```py
from itertools import cycle

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in cycle(my_list):
    print(i)
```

This will cycle `my_list` infinitely until you break the loop